# Dialog "Connected to Database <DB_NAME>" hangs too long

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Each time a member of our team tries to do something with the database (create entity from table, test a query etc.) a dialog "Connected to Database" is shown and it hangs there for a very long time (5-10 minutes). If you cancel it, it closes and reappears again after few seconds and if you do not touch anything it will again periodically disappear and show again.

Perhaps its worth mentioning that our team is producing ADF application with ADF Business Components and project has around 40 root modules (so each has its own database connection).

Is anybody aware of this phenomena and has any ideas about speeding it up ? The thing happens from both JDeveloper and SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

Hey even i faced a similar problem.

Might be you are trying to access a locked object.

Please release the locks of the objects before accesing them.

Also close the sql developer using the task manager.

And now restart it again.

Also you can use the sql developer application in the bin folder as it logs the exact cause of such an error.

Comment: This happens to all team members (10+) all the time. It happens regardless what table is accessed.

Comment: @majkinetor did you follow the above steps and did it resolve? If yes then let us dig more deep and do some more Research.Please up vote my answer as i tried sharing my knowledge